# web.xml can't find dispatcherServlet's servletMapping

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

Building a Spring Web Maven Project in STS; I can't seem to get the web.xml editor to find the servletMapping for the dispatcherServlet, despite it being right there. It keeps telling me that the Servlet Name - "The value is not among the possible selections." The dropdown list flutters like it's looking, but there are no options. My web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!--
    - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

[image: STS Error]

Comment: You didn't include the opening <web-app> tag in your question; is that an omission or is it really missing from your original file?

Comment: Purposeful omission; all the xml tags were giving me formatting headaches.

Comment: I think it's an IDE specific error. Is it stopping you to build your project?